# How to check that Zookeeper server is started using Curator?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

For my tests I am using a test Zookeeper server but I would like to be able to wait until the server is fully started (since I am starting it as part of the test init process).

How is it possible to cleanly check that a (Test) Zookeeper server is correctly started using Curator? Some form of ping/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer and wanted to share.

Curator has a method blockUntilConnected which will wait until it gets a connection from Zookeeper.

```
CuratorFramework curator = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("localhost:" + TestConstants.TEST_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, new RetryOneTime(100));
curator.start();
curator.blockUntilConnected();
```